# Tkinter frame pauses the program. Program wont move on until I close the frame

Tags: python, tkinter

Could someone please explain why this bit of code pauses until I delete the popup Frame?

How do I get the program to leave the message on the pop up frame and continue the program!

```
import winsound
import Tkinter

MessFrame = Tkinter.Tk()
MessFrame.geometry('800x400+200+200')
MessFrame.title('Main Frame')
Framelabel = Tkinter.Label(MessFrame, text='Text Here', fg= 'red')
Framelabel.place(x=10,y=10)
MessFrame.mainloop()

winsound.Beep(500,1000)
```

Edit 1 - I was hoping it would display the "text" - leave the Frame / text displayed and then "beep"
The beep doesnt happen until the Frame is closed!

Comment: what do you expect it to do?

Comment: The method MessFrame.mainloop() does not exit until the you quit the GUI, you'll need to somehow call the Beep() before you get into mainloop(), do it in a separate thread, or schedule it with after().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
import winsound
import Tkinter
import threading

def create_frame():
    MessFrame = Tkinter.Tk()
    MessFrame.geometry('800x400+200+200')
    MessFrame.title('Main Frame')
    Framelabel = Tkinter.Label(MessFrame, text='Text Here', fg= 'red')
    Framelabel.place(x=10,y=10)
    MessFrame.mainloop()


t1 = threading.Thread(target=create_frame)
t1.start()

winsound.Beep(500,1000)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Its so easy and obvious once you know that word "Theading" Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import winsound
import Tkinter

MessFrame = Tkinter.Tk()
MessFrame.geometry('800x400+200+200')
MessFrame.title('Main Frame')
Framelabel = Tkinter.Label(MessFrame, text='Text Here', fg= 'red')
Framelabel.place(x=10,y=10)
winsound.Beep(500,1000) # put beep before mainloop()
MessFrame.mainloop()
```

Any lines after mainloop() will only be executed when you exit the mainloop by exiting the program.

Comment: Many thanks Padraic, this does answer my question, however now that I've been introduced to "threading" by Northcats I can see the future oportunitys. Cheers